# trim off string in mysql

Tags: mysql

trimming off a part of the string in mysql

So I would like to trim off everything after the comma in my mysql sql entries:

for example,

Smith, Jane

I would like the record to return just Smith

I can figure out how to trim off certain characters and spaces, but I have trouble saying "take off everything right of the comma".

I would do the trimming in php after the results come in but I have some concats going, so I want to get it done in mysql first.

Comment: combine the INSTR() and the SUBSTR() functions. (or LOCATE() as zerkms said)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)

```
select substring_index('Smith,Jane', ',', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index